# Dell Latitude E6540 keeps restarting after turning it off

Tags: dell-latitude

I just got a Dell Latitude E6540, but every time I try to turn it off, it restarts automatically. It is running on a 64b Win 7 OS. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How long until it turns back on?  What's plugged into it? Is it plugged into a network by any chance?  What have you tried already in diagnosing? If you disconnect it from everything, does it still do it?  If you boot in safe mode and then shut down, does it still do it?  Are you actually shutting down or just hibernating/sleeping?  What reports as the last device to wake it (`powercfg -lastwake`)?

Comment: If you've just got it, send it back!

Answer (score 0):

In the power settings, there is a setting that controls the power button. Perhaps it is set for restart instead of off